# Sql Where there is records with same field values but different timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, exists

I am figuring out how to write in my where clause there there are records with the same field value but different timestamp.

The tables looks something like this

```
ID       NotificationID        DateTime
1        55555                 2018-01-29 23:00:36.983
2        55555                 2018-01-25 18:38:09.513
3        55555                 2018-01-25 18:38:09.513
4        55555                 2018-01-25 18:38:09.513
```

If there is a record like `ID = 1` which has the same **NotificationID** as `#2, #3, #4` but it has a different datetime, then true

if the table just have `#2, #3, and #`4 with the same **NotificationID** and DateTime, then false

How can I write something in the where clause to tell me that this a record like ID#1 is true.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The required output is missing, however, to find rows where there is a second row with the same `NotificationID` but different `timestamp` you may use `EXISTS`

```
select ID, NotificationID, timestamp
from your_table t1
where exists(
  select 1
  from your_table t2
  where t1.NotificationID = t2.NotificationID and
        t1.timestamp != t2.timestamp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this** -- I have generated two solutions of you.

```
CREATE TABLE notify
(
     ID       INT
    ,NotificationID INT
    ,[DateTime] DATETIME
)
GO

INSERT INTO notify VALUES
(1,55555,'2018-01-29 23:00:36.983'),
(2,55555,'2018-01-25 18:38:09.513'),
(3,55555,'2018-01-25 18:38:09.513'),
(4,55555,'2018-01-25 18:38:09.513')

INSERT INTO notify VALUES 
(6,11111,GETDATE()),
(7,11111,GETDATE())
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
SELECT Id,NotificationID,[DateTime],CASE WHEN a <> b THEN 'False' else 'True' End co FROM 
(
    SELECT * , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NotificationID) a , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NotificationID,[DateTime]) b
    FROM notify
)k

Id          NotificationID DateTime                co
----------- -------------- ----------------------- -----
6           11111          2018-01-30 18:44:18.170 True
7           11111          2018-01-30 18:44:18.170 True
2           55555          2018-01-25 18:38:09.513 False
3           55555          2018-01-25 18:38:09.513 False
4           55555          2018-01-25 18:38:09.513 False
1           55555          2018-01-29 23:00:36.983 False

(6 rows affected)
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```
SELECT NotificationID,MAX(CASE WHEN a <> b THEN 'False' else 'True' End) co 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NotificationID) a , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NotificationID,[DateTime]) b
    FROM notify
)k GROUP BY NotificationID



NotificationID co
-------------- -----
11111          True
55555          False

(2 rows affected)
```